# Accesing an remote enterprise bean within a simple Java class

Tags: java, ejb, jndi

Here's my Java class

```
import endpoint.NewSessionRemote;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class HelloClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            NewSessionRemote hello = (NewSessionRemote) ctx.lookup("endpoint.NewSessionRemote");
            System.out.println(hello.stringChange(4));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this class I'm getting an exception.

```
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: endpoint.NewSessionRemote not found
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:188)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:74)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:129)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:154)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:687)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:227)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1706)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1088)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:223)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:806)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:563)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2567)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:555)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

All the other enterprise bean classes are written according to the EJB 3.0 standard.
Your valuable contribution is expected.

**Solution**

The exception was

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: endpoint.NewSessionRemote not found
```

It occurs because the JNDI name that was given by the application side didn't match the servser's (Glassfish) actual JNDI name, so I did was check the JNDI tree in Glassish through its admin console (vendor specific) and I did notice that the JNDI for the  **NewSessionRemote** interface (which is the business interface of the session bean **NewSessionBean**) is different from the name which I have given in the application side. So how did this happen then suddenly something came in to my mind that's the **ejb-jar.xml** there is another name JNDI name assigned to the same **NewSessionRemote** using  tag. So I simply remove it and redeploy EJB module. That's it.

Comment: The problem has solved thanks for your help.

Comment: Well how about you post some details about the solution so that others with the same problem will learn from your experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using JNDI, you're using an API that requires a specific configuration underlying it in order to connect to the server (see the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) for details on what that configuration is). For example, `java.naming.factory.initial` is the property which indicates which implementation of JNDI you want to use.

Now, when running code inside a JavaEE server, this configuration is available implicitly, and all you need to do is what you have done in your code - instantiate `InitialContext`, and perform a lookup. However, when running outside the server, this implicit configuration is not present, and so you need to configure your `InitialContext` explicitly.

Your sample code uses a `main()` method, which suggests that you're running outside the container. The config you need will depend on your specific application server, you'll need to look up that documentation to see what config to supply.

Comment: Hi I did manage to overcome this problem, but now I'm getting another exception

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have no RMI registry (i.e. active server) you are `lookingUp()` against.

You supplied no `Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY` variable, so the lookup should be a valid URL, which it is not.

Hence, you should put something like this on your `env` (on the `iCtx`):

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
```

I suggest you read the the simple examples over at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-rmi.html