# CreateException and NamingException after trying to inject one EJB into another

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm using JEE6 with Glassfish 3.1 and Eclipse helios. I've been running several EJB's, servlets, and JPA with a database. Now I just tried to create another EJB @Statless and @LocalBean.  When I inject this bean into another bean so that I can call it from there I get deployment errors.

```
  [#|2011-12-27T19:15:14.703-0700|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.ad    min.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|
Exception while loading the app : javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization      failed for Singleton Driver
javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Driver
    at     com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:547)
    at     com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:79)
```

And

```
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:538)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:726)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:247)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:449)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
```

And finally:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.logic.bean/tclient,Remote 3.x interface =com.thrift.ThriftClient,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.thrift.ThriftClient,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.thrift.ThriftClient#com.thrift.ThriftClient' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.thrift.ThriftClient#com.thrift.ThriftClient' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.thrift.ThriftClient#com.thrift.ThriftClient not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1106)
```

This is the new EJB code:

```
...imports...
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ThriftClient {


public ThriftClient(){}

...other code....
```

and how I inject it:

```
@EJB ThriftClient tclient;
```

I'm injecting it into another stateless bean that has other EJB injections that work.

Comment: possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620803/accesing-an-remote-enterprise-bean-within-a-simple-java-class still working on it.

Comment: I'm looking in the client module and there is nothing generated there. Aren't EJB interfaces supposed to be added to this folder in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in Glassfish console if the bean deployed correctly and under what JNDI name. I know that it should work out of the box, but maybe it's worth playing with @EJB annotation parameters to make it point to right JNDI name. This can help you finding the real problem as it is clearly related to JNDI naming. You may also try to find the bean through explicit JNDI lookup instead of injecting it and maybe you'll notice the problem then.

Comment: I get an error when it tries to deploy, saying to check the server logs.

Comment: cannot Deploy XRSSear
Deployment Error for module: XRSSear: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Driver. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: Are the EJB annotation parameters like @EJB (name = /...name)

Comment: Well using JNDI lookup has at least stopped the compile and deployment errors. But I think I could be getting some problems at runtime because it's not checking the lookup address string. In fact I'm pretty sure what I typed isn't the proper fully qualified location of the bean...

Comment: As I suspected I'm no longer getting compile or deployment and server errors by removing the CDI but now it's simply not working at runtime when I try to use the JNDI referenced resource. I'm going to mark your answer as correct as it is most likely some naming or reference problem but I have not fixed my problem yet so I'll ask a new question with the new information.